# Mule ESB 3 transformer cannot be converted to MessageProcessor

Tags: mule

I'm trying to follow the transformer example in the documentation that converts a string input into a list of URLs, but it's throwing an error.

The example is here:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Transformer+Annotation#TransformerAnnotation-WorkingwithCollections

My code for the transformer is copy-pasted from theirs.

When I first did it, I set the transformer by putting in my config xml:

```
<custom-transformer class="com.test.transformer.StringToListTransformer" doc:name="StringToUrlList"/>
```

Noting the requirement to 'register' the transformer, I later added in the beginning of the file (after the opening tag):

```
<spring:bean id="stringToListTransformer" class="com.test.transformer.StringToListTransformer"/>
```

However, when I run the app, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.test.transformer.StringToListTransformer] to required type [org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor] for property 'messageProcessors[3]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a class annotated with `@Transformer` as a `custom-transformer` because it is not a real `org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor`. Only real message processors can be used directly in the XML configuration and invoked explicitly.

As the [doc for `@Transformer`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/transformer-annotation) says:

> There is no mechanism in Mule 3.x to actually invoke a transformer which is being constructed from an annotated method.

If you want to have your transformer kick-in in a flow, you'll need to use:

```
<auto-transformer returnClass="java.util.List.class"/>
```

assuming it returns a list and there are no other suitable registered transformers with a higher priority.

Otherwise, create a real transformer by extending `org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer` and then use it with `custom-transformer`.

Comment: Thanks, just getting started w/ Mule and I guess I misunderstood their walk-through on the resolvers.

Comment: Broken link - I think you want: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/transformer-annotation

Comment: @kaybee99 Thank you, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

please use Java Component not Java Transformer..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).